# php system function gives unusual output

Tags: php, command

my php code

```
$last_line = system('service airtime-media-monitor status');
echo $last_line;
```

my browser displays

```
    AIRTIME_STATUS_URL             = [1;32mhttp://localhost:80/api/status/format/json/api_key/%%api_key%%[0m
AIRTIME_SERVER_RESPONDING      = [1;32mOK[0m
KERNEL_VERSION                 = [1;32m2.6.32-21-generic[0m
MACHINE_ARCHITECTURE           = [1;32mi686[0m
TOTAL_MEMORY_MBYTES            = [1;32m2051244[0m
TOTAL_SWAP_MBYTES              = [1;32mUNKNOWN[0m
AIRTIME_VERSION                = [1;32m2.3.1[0m
OS                             = [1;32mUbuntu 10.04 LTS i686[0m
CPU                            = [1;32mIntel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz[0m
WEB_SERVER                     = [1;32mApache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)[0m
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_PROCESS_ID      = [1;32m1195[0m
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_RUNNING_SECONDS = [1;32m121517[0m
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_MEM_PERC        = [1;32m0.5%[0m
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_CPU_PERC        = [1;32m0.4%[0m
LIQUIDSOAP_PROCESS_ID          = [1;32m4362[0m
LIQUIDSOAP_RUNNING_SECONDS     = [1;32m4564[0m
LIQUIDSOAP_MEM_PERC            = [1;32m0.7%[0m
LIQUIDSOAP_CPU_PERC            = [1;32m11.4%[0m
MEDIA_MONITOR_PROCESS_ID       = [1;32m1489[0m
MEDIA_MONITOR_RUNNING_SECONDS  = [1;32m121509[0m
MEDIA_MONITOR_MEM_PERC         = [1;32m0.5%[0m
MEDIA_MONITOR_CPU_PERC         = [1;32m0.0%[0m
-- Your installation of Airtime looks OK!
-- Your installation of Airtime looks OK!null
```

and this is how the command actually displays this

```
AIRTIME_STATUS_URL             = http://localhost:80/api/status/format/json/api_key/%%api_key%%                                        
AIRTIME_SERVER_RESPONDING      = OK
KERNEL_VERSION                 = 2.6.32-21-generic
MACHINE_ARCHITECTURE           = i686
TOTAL_MEMORY_MBYTES            = 2051244
TOTAL_SWAP_MBYTES              = UNKNOWN
AIRTIME_VERSION                = 2.3.1
OS                             = Ubuntu 10.04 LTS i686
CPU                            = Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz
WEB_SERVER                     = Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_PROCESS_ID      = 1195
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_RUNNING_SECONDS = 121187
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_MEM_PERC        = 0.5%
PLAYOUT_ENGINE_CPU_PERC        = 0.0%
LIQUIDSOAP_PROCESS_ID          = 4362
LIQUIDSOAP_RUNNING_SECONDS     = 4234
LIQUIDSOAP_MEM_PERC            = 0.7%
LIQUIDSOAP_CPU_PERC            = 11.4%
MEDIA_MONITOR_PROCESS_ID       = 1489
MEDIA_MONITOR_RUNNING_SECONDS  = 121179
MEDIA_MONITOR_MEM_PERC         = 0.5%
MEDIA_MONITOR_CPU_PERC         = 0.0%
-- Your installation of Airtime looks OK!
```

Question : so what is the problem with the system function, and where is the rest of the values coming from as i am expecting the web browser to echo as shown by my commnad, and how do I fix it

PS: note I ran the PHP page and the command a few seconds apart so the values are a little off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [ascii color codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), the `service` doesn't seem to detect if the calling terminal supports them or not. <del>You can try to get rid of them with echo</del>. You can try [sed snippets like these](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed).

Comment: Ah, unfortunately the system('echo "$(service airtime-media-monitor status)"'); is not doing anything, so i think i will end up using the preg_replace to blank them off.

Answer (score 1):

Your program uses shell colors. The `[1;32m` is consumed by your shell, but not in verbatim output.
See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43408/printing-colored-text-using-echo